# List all users who voted on a node with their ratings

Tags: views, rating

I am using [fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) module for voting on nodes. For each node I would like to create a list of users who have voted on this node and the rating they have given. I am trying to do this using **Views 3** but I don't see any relationship which can give me this.

I tried doing this using both the node base table and user base table in Views.

Any ideas how I can go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use node as your base table, you can add the relation `Content: Votes`. This will expose all Votes on that node. From there you can add the fields `Votes: User` and `Votes: Value` that can be displayed in a table or something.

[image]

Comment: I swear this was not working earlier. But it does now :P

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I am getting only the first user (in terms of user ID) who voted on the article and not a list of all users who voted on the article, how can I achieve this?

Comment: My bad, I had limited only 10 entries and I was unable to see multiple entries for a node. This works perfect! Only question I have, is there a way to accept the UID as a URL parameter and then filter out results only for that user?

Comment: Hi Raj, you might be able to add a contextual filter for the vote user's uid and fill it with a default value from the URL.